# MPMoviePlayerViewController issue in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mpmovieplayer

I am new to swift in my app I want to display video using MPMoviePlayerViewController. I follow the following code every thing working fine but when tap in toolbar Video is playing in full mode and again if i tap in video it is playing in center of the screen.Here the problem  what i faced is i placed first frame of video as background image of MPMoviePlayerViewController when video playing in center of the screen then in the top place of MPMoviePlayerViewController  background image is displaying . my question is how to hide background image if video plays in center of the screen  any one have idea regarding this issue ?

Here image frame is also same as videoview

```
movieObj.moviePlayer.controlStyle = .Embedded 
movieObj.moviePlayer.scalingMode = .Fill
movieObj..moviePlayer.frame = self.videoview.bounds
movieObj..moviePlayer.backroudview.addsubview(image)
self.view.addSubview(movieObj)
movieObj. moviePlayer.play()
```

Comment: MPMoviePlayerViewController is deprecated. Don't use it (unless you have to be compatible with iOS 7 or something wacky like that).

Comment: @matt can u tell me replacement of MPMoviePlayerViewController framework

Comment: AVPlayerViewController